# Using MySQLi connection on multiple functions (OO)

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Switching from mysql to mysqli, I was used to create a connection first then use it within several functions and close it at the end of the script (I'm not an expert :)).

However, I noticed that now, that isn't possible anymore with mysqli. I have:

```
$db = new mysqli('localhost', 'username', 'password', 'database');

if($db->connect_errno > 0){
   die('Unable to connect to database [' . $db->connect_error . ']');
}

$db->set_charset("utf8");
```

Then, several function that need to use that connection like

```
function x(){
    $db->query(....);
}
```

I get an error while doing that as the $db isn't an object inside the functions.

I did a little research and adding

```
global $db;
```

before calling the query inside each function solved the issue. But considering I have hundreds of functions, do I need to add that at the beginning of each function? Isn't there another way to set that connection to be publicly available to all functions?

I'm finding mysqli a little more complicate than mysql, perhaps I was just used to, but even using the procedural you need to pass extra parameters that mysql didn't need, or am I missing something?

Comment: You should read up on dependency injection. Using global statements is very poor coding practice. That is not going to save you from needing to modify your functions, but it would give you a much less fragile code base going forward.

Comment: I agree with @MikeBrant. Basically, this is your solution... `function x(mysqli $db) { $db->query(...); }`

Comment: So basically I either pass the connection object as a parameter to the functions or I create a class to query the DB and call it every time I need to do a query, right?